# WolframClient output convert to python complex array

Tags: complex, python, wolfram-client

I encountered the following issue with `WolframClient`. I have a `my.function` file which contains some function that takes some parameters (7 floats) as input and returns a nested list of complex numbers in Mathematica. I want to call it via python and treat the output as a `numpy.ndarray` of complex numbers. I do the following:

```
with WolframLanguageSession() as session:
        my_function = session.function(wl.Get(path_to_function))

        x = my_function(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8)

        print(x)
```

which gives me something like this:

```
((((Complex[-2.9851335011862212, -0.5581051654634444], Complex[-0.34914756979863104, 0.38713532072098944], Complex[0.02846108320428109, 0.03283335816887564]), (Complex[2.9114417580613257, -0.058550143608501304], Complex[0.041982819472082836, -0.2399283469968325], 0), (Complex[-0.29788041688768496, 0.16668305088796254], 0, 0)), ((Complex[1.607048536309744, 0.054911153529431656], Complex[0.03322853020335367, -0.11167319057887276], 0), (Complex[-0.3015173117518156, 0.12541388543997334], 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((Complex[-0.07510109944668442, 0.02144870241235377], 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))), (((Complex[1.7446313085976066, 0.9785287503847628], Complex[0.15511366918115133, -0.17146659375916984], 0), (Complex[-0.6471782663657613, -0.03367309746041122], 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((Complex[-0.3056298195051441, -0.05182365243220163], 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))), (((Complex[-0.25138505704186276, -0.17724520875129096], 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))))
```

which python parses as a tuple, which is fine because I can convert a tuple to array. However, I've got a problem with the complex numbers: each non-zero element of the tuples is a `wolframclient.language.expression.WLFunction` which I don't know how to convert to a python number. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution to do the casting?

A workaround of course is to return the real and imaginary part of the result seperately:

```
Return[{Re[res],Im[res]}];
```

Comment: In most cases you do not need `Return` to return a value from a function. Functions just return the last value you calculate in them. You can also take advantage of [`ReIm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) to return `ReIm[res]`, which accomplishes the same thing you propose.